# saving textarea with no-wrap is causing weird chars to php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a textarea to user input a query. So i'm using this to prevent wrapping:

```
textarea{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

so, then I input a SQL like this

```
SELECT
   field1
FROM my table
```

This is correctly saved in mysql `utf8_general_ci` field, but when I try to `var_dump()` saved content, it shows:

```
SELECT
 Ã  Ã field1
FROM my table
```

If I remove css from textarea, it works fine. But I need no-wrap.

Comment: Could you insert this on jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the browser is (poorly) implementing `white-space:nowrap` by silently converting all spaces to non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`).

This character is `0xA0` in single-byte character sets like ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252.

However it is being sent encoded as UTF-8.

This character, when converted to UTF-8, happens to convert to the two-byte sequence `0xC2A0`, which when "cast" back to single characters gives `0xC2` followed by `0xA0`, or Ã followed by [NBSP] (it's mostly coincidental that the second byte is the same as the original character, don't take any meaning from it)

I would suggest using the older, more compatible way of disabling wrapping:

```
<textarea wrap="off">...</textarea>
```

This will disable wrapping, and you should stop seeing those strange characters.